# add class to nested div if class exists and to all if class doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK I have the following structure:

```
<div class="class">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
</div>
<div class="class">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test reserved">test</div>
</div>
<div class="class">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
</div>
```

and this js:

```
$('.test').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('checkin');
});
```

How do I add a class to all the nested `.test` divs in between the `.checkin` and `.reserved` and if in the case of `.reserved` not existing then add the class to all of the `.test` divs?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vimes1984/SvFAA/1/)

Comment: There are no nested `.test` divs

Comment: what do you mean by `in between .checkin and .reserved`?

Comment: the .test div is nested in the .class div?

Comment: the checkin class is being added on click...

Comment: You should probably clarify this question...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.test').on('click', function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('.reserved').andSelf().addClass('checkin');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/
http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/

Comment: You also want siblings in every other parent?

Comment: yes until it hits the next decendant reserved div or if the reserved div is not there until the end

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.test').on('click',function(){
$(this).addClass('checkin').nextUntil('.preserved').addClass('checkin');   
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).parent().nextAll('.class').length;i++){
        var $class=$(this).parent().nextAll('.class').eq(i);
        if($class.find('.reserved').length ==0){

        }else{
            $class.find('.test:first').nextUntil('.reserved').addClass('checkin');
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SvFAA/6/)

Comment: Ok this is perfect until the reserved is prior to the checkin on non existant then it fails...

Comment: Ah i see, i'll check it out when i come back home, got to go now

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**`.hasclass()`**](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

> **Description**: Determine whether any of the matched elements are
>   assigned the given class.

```
$(this).hasClass('reserved') // retuns boolean value
```

Comment: ok my problem here arrises if the reserved class is prior to the check in class in this case i need to find the next reserved not the prior reserved...

Comment: I don't see how this will add the class to all the elements up to a certain point?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery nextUntil() function : http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

This will work well for your exact question, but if you wan to tweak it a little bit, you should go back to the stupid brute method : take the array and loop on it with boolean.

```
$('.test').on('click', function(e){
    //add the class to your target
    $(e.target).addClass('checkin');

    //get an array of all the .test divs in the .class div you click
    var arTests = $(e.target).parent().find('div.test');
    //if you want to loop on all the .test of the page, just go like that :
    // var arTests = $('div.test');

    //boolean to check in the loop
    var boCheckinPased = false;
    var boReservedPassed = false;

    for(var i = 0; i < arTests.length; i++) {
        if($(arTests[i]).hasClass('checkin')) boCheckinPased = true;
        if($(arTests[i]).hasClass('reserved')) boReservedPassed = true;

        //if passed the first checkin and not yet the reserved, add the class
        if(boCheckinPased && !boReservedPassed) $(arTests[i]).addClass('checkin')
    }
});
```

I did update a jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/SvFAA/8/

Answer (score 0):

Less code is better code:

```
$('.test').on('click', function(){
    var elements = $('.class .test');
    elements.each(function(key, value) {
        if (!$(elements[key]).hasClass('reserved')) {
            $(elements[key]).addClass('checkin');       
        }
    });
});
```

elements: is a list of objects

key: is the position of a each element in the list of elements

value: is the object itself